# Condensing Javascript/jQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to start by thanking anyone who can help me condense this piece of Javascript/jQuery code.

```
        jQuery(function() {

            jQuery('#pitem-1').click(function(e) {
                jQuery("#image-1").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                    jQuery("#image-1").find("input:first").focus();
                }});

                e.preventDefault();
            });        

            jQuery('#pitem-2').click(function(e) {
                jQuery("#image-2").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                    jQuery("#image-2").find("input:first").focus();
                }});

                e.preventDefault();
            });

            jQuery('#pitem-3').click(function(e) {
                jQuery("#image-3").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                    jQuery("#image-3").find("input:first").focus();
                }});

                e.preventDefault();
            });

            jQuery('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
        });
```

Basically each #pitem-ID opens the same #image-ID in a popup.

Thanks again to anyone who can help.

Jack

Comment: What's stopping you from using a loop?

Comment: Start by replacing jQuery with $.

Comment: I'm using jQuery instead of $ to prevent conflict with Prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id^="pitem-"]').click(function(e) {
    var numb = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $("#image-"+numb).lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
         $(this).find("input:first").focus();
    }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});        

$('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
```

Comment: This is what I was after. It works for the first 3 items with the IDs 1,2,3 however I then jump to item 50 and it doesn't work. Any idea why?

EDIT: It doesn't work with any IDs above 9 (double figures) - is it possible to change that?

Comment: @JackClarke - updated my answer to take two digits aswell, actually it will take any digit after the `-` !

Answer (score 4):

Your functions all look pretty much the same, which is a clue that you should probably move that functionality out into something that can be called:

```
function createHandler(id) {
    return function (e) {
        $(id).lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
            $(id).find("input:first").focus();
        }});

        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
 $('#pitem-2').bind('click', createHandler("#image-2"));
```

Comment: But, this still repeats the code to install the event handler three times rather than creating a single event handler that handles all three objects (see other answers that do that).

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Combine multiple objects into the selector with a common event handler
2. Use `this` to refer to the object that triggered the event
3. Derive the image ID from the id of the object that generated the event.

That lets you use one piece of code to handle the action for all three objects:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#pitem-1, #pitem-2, #pitem-3").click(function() {
        var image$ = $("#" + this.id.replace("pitem", "image"));
        image$.lighbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
                    image$.find("input:first").focus();
        }});
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    jQuery('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without context it is hard to tell, but is it necessary to have a unique ID for each `pitem`? Why not use a CSS class instead of a ID like so:

```
<div class="pitem">
<div id="image1"><img ... /></img>
</div>
...
<div class="pitem">
<div id="image3"><img ... /></img>
</div>
```

And then use the class selector in jQuery to add the click functionality all of them at once:

```
$(".pitem").click(function(e) {
  var currentItem = e.target;
  ...
  e.preventDefault();
});
```