# Condensing Jquery to be cleaner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried implementing this from another story and it did not work...I'm trying to do something similar.

[Condensing Javascript/jQuery Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359594/condensing-javascript-jquery-code/48451108?noredirect=1#comment83895969_48451108)

I didn't know if it were still active.

I am trying to convert

```
$("#coll-1").click(function(){
    $(".coll-1").stop().slideToggle();
    return false;
});

$("#coll-2").click(function(){
    $(".coll-2").stop().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Into this

```
$('[id^="coll-"]').click(function(){
    alert("This works?");
    $(this).find('[class^="coll-"]').stop().slideToggle();
    return false;
});

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cwrap nursel">
  <span class="colour"></span>
  <div class="card card-block">

<hr/>

<div class="col-xs-12 nill">
    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      <span class="coll-2">
      Maecenas mattis purus nunc, et molestie risus porttitor a. Phasellus ex lacus, viverra sed tempus at, cursus quis tortor. Cras tempor mollis.
      </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 nill mar_bott">
<a id="coll-2" href="" class="">Show more  <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

So far it's not working.

Comment: Could you share your HTML code?

Comment: In your code, `$(this)` points to the element you want. You're already there. Why are you doing a `find()`?

Comment: @Snowmonkey no it doesn't... one selector is using `id` and the other is using `class`. `.find()` looks for things nested inside `$(this)` it doesn't look through the whole DOM again

Comment: so you arent' trying to emulate your original code, which selected the id and toggled that element.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, looks like you are too closely following the other example. Your JQuery id find should be `$('[id^="coll"]')` as your code does not have hyphens. Then if the element you are looking to stop is a child element, you can correct the find to be `$(this).find('[class^="coll"]').stop().slideToggle();`

Comment: `$('[id^="coll-"]')` should probably be `$('[id^="col-"]')`

Comment: And in your original, as @Barmar said, your class and id are the same -- in your attempt to reduce, you are using `^coll-` rather than `^col`.

Comment: @Snowmonkey He's consistent with the naming scheme in both versions, but it seems like it changed between versions.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be searching in `$(this)`. Just take the current element's ID, and convert it to a class selector.

```
$("[id^=coll-]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theClass = this.id;
    $("." + theClass).stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Please note that `class` is a reserved word in Javascript.

Comment: Keep in mind OP added an extra hyphen when looking at other solutions. The selector is likely `$("[id^=col]")`

Comment: @PhillipThomas I noticed that, I assumed that he's also changing his HTML to `id="coll-1"` and `class="coll-1"`

Comment: Where's the `return false;`?

Comment: I'd go `$("[id^=col-]").click(function() {
    return !$("." + this.id).stop().slideToggle();
});`

Comment: That's how I would probably write it myself, this just makes it clearer for pedagogic reasons.

Comment: Except I wouldn't do `return !...`. That's unnecessarily cryptic. I'd actually call `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Your code still has the *`$('[id^="coll-"]')` should probably be `$('[id^="col-"]')`* problem.

Comment: Well, the question is about shortening/condensing code.

Comment: @connexo What he obviously means is how to do DRY, not minifying.

Comment: Where does `^id=col-` come from? The original was `^id=col`, the new is `^id=coll-`.

Comment: I added my html. Looking through your comments right now.

Comment: $('[id^="coll-"]').click(function(){ 
        return !$("." + this.id).stop().slideToggle(); 
    }); this works but I don't understand why the class^="coll-" didn't

Comment: Where would I replace the e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @KeithJeter `class^="coll-"` will affect all elements whose class begins with `coll-`, not just the ones with the same number as the element you clicked on.

Comment: @KeithJeter If you click on `id=coll-1`, you only want to toggle `class="coll-1"`, not all `class="coll-#"`

Comment: @KeithJeter I've changed my code to show `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: This has all been very helpful. Thanks @barmar. I ended up adding the stopPropagation() as well because I can't do a return false. So the final lil powerful guy looks like this $('[id^="coll-"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation();
    return !$("." + this.id).stop().slideToggle();
});

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to 'reduce' your original code, this would do:

```
$("#col1, #col2").click(function(){
  $(this).stop().slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This assumes the element you would like to stop animating is the one you clicked. Which without the HTML could be the case...

Comment: Read the original code again. The click handler is on an ID, the `stop` and `slideToggle` is on a class.

Comment: His original code is `$("#col1")` and slide toggles `$(".col1")`. `$("#col1") !== $(".col1")`

Comment: dang it, I missed the id-to-class thing. sigh.